# Is it possible to simply export data from mongodb 3.2 and import it to mognodb 3.4?

Tags: mongodb, database-migration, data-migration

I have done this ( exported from MongoDB 3.2 and imported it into a MongoDB 3.4 instance ). currently, everything is okay and there are no problems reported by our users. but I am sort of worried about problems in the future. unfortunately, I'm not an expert MongoDB administer.

So I need some help.
How can I run a kind of health check on the new instance to make sure everything is OK?

I've set up a new MongoDB server and imported data from my old server. then, I changed the database host and credentials in my application settings.

Comment: Should be no problem at all, because the BSON format does not change. You would only have to check your application code because of new or removed functions.

Comment: I have an Open edX instance. it is upgraded to the new version and works like a charm. I have to study BSON format then. so could you post an answer? it would be great if includes some further reading references. thanks  @WernfriedDomscheit